# Cannot render material ui table row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I am trying to render a table from material UI, with some data that I fetched. I know my data is fetching correctly, because I am able to console.log it from its saved state, however when I try to map this inside the table row, it does not work. My table successfully generates its headers, just has blank data for the body.

```
gameDataTableRow = scheduleData => {
    scheduleData.map(game => {
      console.log(game.scheduled); <--These console logs will display data properly
      console.log(game.venue.name);
      console.log(game.home.name);
      console.log(game.away.name);
      return (
        <TableRow key={game.venue.id}>
          <TableCell>{game.scheduled}</TableCell> <-- These cells wont render in the table row
          <TableCell>{game.venue.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{game.home.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{game.away.name}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      );
    });
  };

render() {
    console.log(this.state.games);
    return (
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell numeric>Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Venue</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Home</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Away</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>{this.gameDataTableRow(this.state.games)}</TableBody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In arrow functon, if you are writing block `{..}`, you must use the explicit `return` statement.

These two are same:

```
let foo1 = (val1) => val1 * 2;
let foo1 = (val1) => { return val1 * 2 };
```

Solution to the question:

```
gameDataTableRow = scheduleData => {
   return scheduleData.map(game => { //Added return statement
    console.log(game.scheduled); <--These console logs will display data properly
    console.log(game.venue.name);
    console.log(game.home.name);
    console.log(game.away.name);
    return (
    <TableRow key={game.venue.id}>
      <TableCell>{game.scheduled}</TableCell> <-- These cells wont render in the table row
      <TableCell>{game.venue.name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{game.home.name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{game.away.name}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: Omg, thanks for this! ive been stuck on this for so long. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear from you. Happy coding. :-)